# avoiding recompilation when types don't change

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I have a large Haskell project with many packages built with stack. I have long recompilation times when I make trivial changes in a core model or some configuration data **without changing any types**.

If this were C, I would have to only recompile the changed object file and then re-link the whole project. In Haskell I have to recompile every module which depends on the changed module.

I understand that this enables all kinds of compiler optimizations, but I am looking for a way to sidestep this in order to have quick recompilation during development. Is there any way to accomplish this in Haskell?

Comment: It's not clear to me what sort of change you're referring to. Is a "core model" not a type? You might try splitting things up into smaller modules (as in e.g. the common `Foo/Types.hs` idiom) It sounds like you also want to disable optimizations during development. In modern GHC you can also just run the typechecker which is often what you want

Comment: I mean like adding a print statement without changing the `IO ()` type, or changing some model parameter without changing the `Double` type.

Comment: There is an open issue for `stack typecheck` here https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/977 as well. Does disabling optimizations avoid recompilation or just speed up compilation?

Comment: have you try `stack build --fast` ?

Comment: Yes I am usually using `stack build --fast`

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that illustrates the problem?  I am not able to duplicate it in the simple example of one module depending on a `Double` parameter defined and modified in separate module.  Providing I always build with `--fast`, only the modified module gets rebuilt.

Comment: You are right, I cannot reproduce it with --fast. I must have been measuring incorrectly before.